# textColor attribute is not working after update to sdk 25.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textcolor

After I update my sdk into 25.1.1, the whole textColor property to the TextView and button is not working. it's just using the Default theme color. how can i change the textcolor from xml widget.

Comment: <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/offer_date_range"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

Answer (score 0):

Try it!!

```
ContextCompat.getColor(textView, R.color.color_name);
```

Comment: Via java file is workingfine. Via XML it's not working in bellow lolipop devices.